# Unable to provide a template for error 403

Tags: python, django

Well, at this moment I know how to make a custom error 404 page (and it actually works in my app). I followed the same strategy step by step to make a 403 page, but to no avail. So, this is what I have done:

```
#root urls.py 
handler403 = 'blog.views.custom_403'

#blog views.py
def custom_403(request):
    template = loader.get_template('blog/403.html')
    context = RequestContext(request,{})
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Then, in one of my functions I have this code:

```
return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

I thought, it would render `403.html`, but what I see is just a message `403 FORBIDDEN` in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is, you are not raising a 403 exception (as you did for the 404), but simply returning a response with a status code of 403. As [the docs show](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/views/#the-403-http-forbidden-view), you need to raise `django.views.defaults.permission_denied` to trigger the 403 page.

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
...
raise PermissionDenied
```